# Interactions between factors in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

How does one compute interactions using `data.table`?  Specifically, I am trying to get all the unique combinations between successive groupings of columns from right to left (dropping unused levels).  I am using code like this,

```
## Sample data
set.seed(1999)
dat <- setDT(lapply(split(letters[1:9], 1:3), function(l) factor(sample(l, 10, TRUE, (1:3)^3))))
dat
#     1 2 3
#  1: d h i
#  2: g e f
#  3: g h i
#  4: g h i
#  5: d h i
#  6: g h c
#  7: d h i
#  8: g h f
#  9: g e i
# 10: d e i

## All factor combinations from left to right by column
f <- function(...) interaction(..., drop=TRUE)
levs <- Reduce(f, dat, accumulate = TRUE)
res <- unlist(lapply(levs, levels))
#  [1] "d"     "g"     "d.e"   "g.e"   "d.h"   "g.h"   "g.h.c" "g.e.f" "g.h.f"
# [10] "d.e.i" "g.e.i" "d.h.i" "g.h.i"
```

where `res` is the intended result.  It works fine, but I might as well just be using a data.frame since this isn't advantage of any of the internal data.table matching.

This is just worse cause it repeats everything.

```
dat[, Reduce(f, .SD, accumulate = TRUE)]
```

Can I replace base's `interaction` with a fast data.table one?

#### Edit

a larger example with data from `gglot2`

```
data(diamonds, package="ggplot2")
dat <- as.data.table(diamonds)
sdcols <- c("cut", "color", "clarity")  # some factor columns

## Expected output, really just interested in the levels,
## so character instead of factor is fine
levs <- unlist(Reduce(function(...) interaction(..., drop=TRUE),
                      dat[,sdcols,with=FALSE], accumulate = TRUE))
length(levels(levs))  # [1] 316

## Not quite right
levs2 <- dat[, Reduce(function(...) do.call(paste, c(list(...), sep=".")), .SD,
                      accumulate = TRUE), .SDcols=sdcols]
```

Comment: Do you have hundreds of factor levels or columns? I wouldn't expect `interaction` (which just needs to compose combns of factor levels and paste them together..?) to take much time.

Comment: `interactions` should be able to subsist on just the `levels` attribute, eh; why would it need the whole vector? Anyway, since this is a question of performance, maybe you can add an example that takes longer to run. `set.seed(1); n = 1e5; etc`

Comment: Ah ok, didn't know that; never used the function.

Comment: For your example, I think it comes down to `setDT(list(l1,l2))[, do.call(paste, c(.SD,sep=".")), by="V1,V2"]` or the same thing without a `by`. Without `by` is faster here just because you have 100k rows and 90k unique combos of `l1`x`l2`; the `by` way would win if you had fewer combos vs rows, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the OP's example:

```
data(diamonds, package="ggplot2")
dat <- as.data.table(diamonds)
sdcols <- c("cut", "color", "clarity")

DAT <- dat[, sdcols, with=FALSE]
```

Here are a few options

```
f       <- function(...) interaction(..., drop=TRUE)
baseint <- function() lapply(Reduce(f, DAT, accumulate = TRUE), levels)

newint  <- function() lapply(seq_along(DAT), function(nj) do.call(paste, c(
  sep=".",
  unique(DAT[,seq(nj),with=FALSE])
)))

newint2  <- function(){
  DAT0 = unique(DAT)
  res  = vector("list", length(DAT))
  for (k in length(DAT):1){
    res[[k]] <- do.call(paste, c(sep=".",DAT0))
    DAT0[, (length(DAT0)) := NULL]
    DAT0 <- unique(DAT0)
  }
  res
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  base = {baseres = baseint()},
  new  = {newres  = newint()},
  new2 = {newres2 = newint2()},
  times = 3
)

# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#  base 14.110835 14.377433 16.910993 14.644031 18.311072 21.978113     3
#   new  3.335112  3.352311  3.680126  3.369511  3.852634  4.335756     3
#  new2  2.662375  2.843113  3.963925  3.023850  4.614700  6.205549     3

identical(lapply(baseres,sort), lapply(newres,sort))  # TRUE
identical(lapply(baseres,sort), lapply(newres2,sort)) # TRUE
```

The second idea for a new `interaction`, `newint2`, takes these steps:

1. Uniquify data
2. Paste columns
3. Drop rightmost column
4. Repeat from step 1 while any columns are left

---

*Comments.*

This is a very small example, and it's not clear to me what a larger one would look like (where we're talking about saving more than a few milliseconds).

One last one, if you are only need to get the length of the accumulated interactions,

```
dat <- as.data.table(diamonds)
setkeyv(dat, sdcols)
tst <- vector("list", length(sdcols))
for (i in 1:length(sdcols)) tst[[i]] <- uniqueN(rleidv(dat[, sdcols[1:i], with=FALSE]))
```

Comment: @TheTime I'm not sure why `rleidv` is there; `uniqueN` can work on the data.table itself, returning the number of unique rows. Also, for a count, might as well use an `integer` instead of a `list`. `tst <- integer(length(DAT)); for (k in length(DAT):1) tst[k] <- uniqueN(DAT[,seq(k),with=FALSE])`